# In Windows' Run command line, how to open “Cookies”?

Tags: windows-7, cookies

I recently got a new, Windows 7 machine, and I can't find the cookies! .how can i get it through run commnd prompt.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what exactly it is you want to do. Are you wondering where Cookies are stored?

Comment: For Chrome use this `chrome://settings/cookies`, link to see cookies or remove them.

Comment: can u tell me Where is/are the Cookies folder(s) in Windows 7?

Comment: can u share me the command that is used to open folder through command prompt. is it something like "shell :cookies "?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5700746/1286571) question and the question it links to.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as "*the* cookies". Cookies are a feature of webbrowsers, and each webbrowser has its own cookie store. So you need to open the webbrowser you're using, and find its cookies in there.

Comment: ok. thank you . i need the location of cookies folder in my windows 7 system. what is the folder path for that ?

Comment: In general it's not a folder !

Comment: !! where Cookies are stored in our systems?